# How to prevent dismissal of UITabBarController by pushed SFSafariViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm pushing `SFSafariViewController` into `UITabBarController`. But clicking on the Safari Done button dismisses the `UITabBarController`. How to prevent it?

Comment: if you are pushing it, than pop instead of dismiss

Answer (score 0):

If you are Pushing the `SFSafariViewController` try `popViewController` instead of `dismiss`

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Or you can `present` the `SFSafariViewController` instead of pushing it

```
safariViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
safariViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

self.present(safariViewController, animated: false, completion:nil)
```

Comment: 1. Safari view controller always calls dismiss, I'm not able to avoid it
2. present shows Safari view controller modally, the bottom tab bar is hidden and so no way to switch between bar items

Comment: @PeterBalogh Try presenting it `modalPresentationStyle` set to  `overCurrentContext ` it will solve your problem. Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: overCurrentContext presentation style helps :-) Unfortunately another problem has been appeared: when safari view is opened, I switch to another bar item view, than I switch back to safari view and I close it, than the current view is not showed, the tab is empty. I have to switch to another bar item, than switch back to show a view.